# Is there a simple solution to these 2 equations without trying all possible values?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, finite-groups, logarithms, finite-fields, exponentiation

Now I have two equations and the computation is in a finite field GF(*p*), where *p* is a prime.

$x, y$ are unknown, and $a, b$ are known. ($0<y<p-1$, and $0<ax<p-1.$)

$\begin{cases} 
 x^y = a, \\
 y^{ax} = b.
 \end{cases} 
$

Is there a simple solution to solve $x$ and $y$ other than trying all their possible combinations (which is $p^2$ tries)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by $x^y$ where $x$ and $y$ are both elements of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$? If $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$ is nonzero, then the exponent $n$ in the expression $x^n$ naturally takes values in $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks you are right. I just modified it.

Answer (score 0):

I think one thing we can do is to take log on both sides, so that we have:

$
\begin{cases}
y\log{x} = \log{a}, \\
ax\log{y} = \log{b}.
\end{cases}
$

Since $y = \log{a} / \log{x}$, by substituting it to the 2nd equation we have:

$ax\log{(\log{a}/\log{x})} = \log{b}$.

Then by trying all $x$ we can solve this equation. Then it is not far from solving $y$. At least this reduces the complexity from $p^2$ to $p$.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that computing the discrete logarithm is kinda difficult? You do get complexity lower than $p^2$, but calculating $\log_g a$ (w.r.t. some primitive root $g$ modulo $p$) is in general quite difficult.

Comment: That's true. When p is a prime it is hard.